# Agrupamento no Ireport

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid, ireport

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em `Java` onde extraio relatórios em PDF e EXCEL, utilizando **Jasper** com **Ireport(3.7.2)**.Um desses relatórios é necessário ter dados agrupados por determinado elemento.Dei uma pesquisada e só achei resoluções com versões do ireport antigas que ja não se utilizam. Alguém sabe me dizer alguma forma de poder extrair os relatorios com seus devidos agrupamentos?

Abaixo o print da minha tela de consulta, onde devo extrair os dados com esse agrupamento apresentado. A minha dúvida é se é possivel fazer isso no ireport e como? ou uma ideia de como fazer.
[image: tabela]

Comment: Guilherme, [essa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13652866/664577) do SOE responde genericamente como agrupar no iReport 3.x e 5.x. Se você precisar de mais ajuda por você complemente sua pergunta com informações pertinentes ao problema que você está enfrentando.

Comment: Guilherme, se você puder esclarecer melhor sua dificuldade ou até postar uma imagem ilustrando o seu problema vai permitir que o ajudemos melhor.

Comment: Inseri o print da tabela que contem os dados que devem ser exportados.

Comment: Guilherme, embora o iReport tenha evoluído bastante desde a versão 1 até a atual (5.x), o conceito não mudou nada. Grupos continuam sendo grupos. Só mudou o local das opções, menus, barras de ferramentas.

Answer (score 1):

você pode resolver isso la no jrxml

- abra o jrxml pelo irepot
- clique com o botão  direito no nome do report no canto esquerdo da tela
- clique na opção de criar "report group"
- será aberta um tela pedindo o nome do group e pelo o que ele será agrupado

Espero que isso te ajude!